# how to limit my android's app to one device?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I have an application published on google play. I created a customization of that application that will only run on a type of device from a private manufacturer, for which I know the model and other data.

And I want to restrict that app variant to only that device.

According to the Google play console, it allows me with the Device Catalog Manage exclusion rules, but not for a specific app version code.

I thought about changing the name of the package, and that it was another application with a different id, but I would like it to keep the same id and be able to update from the one already created.

What is the correct way to achieve?